# Magento - Save a Product without setting "Use Default Value"

Tags: magento

I have a multi-store setup - StoreA, StoreB and StoreC. And within a controller (using the StoreA url) I'm editing a product as follows:

```
$_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
$_product->load($productId);
$_product->setData('attribute1','somevalue');
$_product->save();
```

If I then go to the Admin / Edit Product for that particular product, I find that attribute1 has been correctly set BUT I also find that if I select StoreA in the "Choose Shop View" I find that all the "Use Default Value" check-boxes (for StoreA) have been set to false.

Questions:

1. How do I modify the code above so the "Use Default Value"
   check-boxes for StoreA remain true
2. Once that the above code has been executed (and the "Use Default
   Value" for StoreA set to false), how do I revert the "Use Default
   Value" values back to true for StoreA?

**Edit:**

Added screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on the 'Use Default Value' check-boxes you are seeing, but there are two things I noticed.

**Using The Factory Pattern**

Your code:

```
$_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
```

Use the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), which is standard in Magento:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

That in itself isn't the problem, but it's something to keep in mind.

**Updating Only The Product Attribute**

Next, if you are only saving a specific attribute it would be quicker (and potentially avoid your problem) if you update only that attribute. Like so:

```
$attribute = array('attribute_code' => 'attribute_value');

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
            ->updateAttributes($_product->getId(), $attribute, 0);
```

[Reference for the updateAttributes() method.](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action.html) My reasoning here is that it's possible default values are being added by saving the entire product, and not just a specific attribute.

If that doesn't help, perhaps a screenshot of what you are seeing could better help me visualize the issue.

Comment: Good idea re Factory Pattern. I have also uploaded a screenshot. Re ->updateAttributes, I'm noticing that the last param is a store ID. I think this is the key - I'll test out. Any idea re part 2 of the question?

Comment: Ah, if you weren't setting the store ID that would be an issue. Did that solve it, or should we troubleshoot further?

Comment: Thanks. Building on your answer I found that you can use Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); to set the default store. This solves (1). To solve (2), I found out that you can set $_product->setName(false) or $_product->setData('attribute',false) - BUT given that I have a lot of attributes to set I am trying to use ->updateAttributes but this is giving the following problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302279/magento-setting-product-attributes-use-default-value-using-updateattributes)