# Magento setting Product Attribute's "Use Default Value" using updateAttributes

Tags: magento

I have a multi-store setup and I am setting a Product's Attribute for a particular store to use the "Use Default Value" option - (ie to use the value in the Store View), as follows:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product->load($productId);
$_product->setStoreId($storeId)->setName(false)->save();
```

This sets the Name attribute of storeId for $productId to use "Use Default Value"

Given that I have a lot of attributes to set I am trying to use:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(array($productId), array('name' => false), $storeId);
```

But this is not setting the "Use Default Value" checkbox to true.

How can I use ->updateAttributes to set a store value to use the "Use Default Value" option?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299145/magento-save-a-product-without-setting-use-default-value

Comment: @OSdave No, this is **not** a duplicate of that question (though I used the same screenshot). This question is specifically about a problem with updateAttributes, whilst in the other question I did not even mention updateAttributes. Longer explanation: Whilst working on the solution for the other question I have encountered a new problem related to the updateAttributes and thus I have asked this question (given that it is a different question).

Comment: What did you finally use to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 4):

The "Use Default Value" flag isn't stored in the database anywhere.

Magento core uses that flag to do this when saving products:

```
   /**
     * Check "Use Default Value" checkboxes values
     */
    if ($useDefaults = $this->getRequest()->getPost('use_default')) {
        foreach ($useDefaults as $attributeCode) {
            $product->setData($attributeCode, false);
        }
    }
```

Before doing some other things.

I would look at `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php) and learn how Magento core does it.

Specifically `saveAction()` and `_initProductSave()`

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really answer the question. The right answer is, unfortunately, that it is not possible via `updateAttributes()`. See also [this Magento SE answer](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33371/142).

Comment: Really though, it does answer the question. The question is essentially "How can I set a store value to use the 'Use Default Value' option?", and while you can't with ->updateAttributes, my answer gives the detail on how you can.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use 0 as the store ID (admin store) which is the same thing as default values in the Magento Admin.

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
    ->updateAttributes(
        array($productId),
        array('name' => false),
        0);
```

If you already set the store view scopes you will have to go in and recheck the use default values or it will override the attribute at the relevant scope.

There may be a way to programmatically set these. I'm uncertain.